# How to establish connection between RFT and PuTTy server?

Tags: rft

I work as an automation tester. Recently got a new task on validating the files opened in PuTTy server. But I do not have any idea how to proceed on this. I am wondering if there is a possibility to establish a connection between RFT and the PuTTy server.

If there is any other way, kindly suggest.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

RFT comes with an Extension for Terminal Based application. Using that extension you can connect to your server. RFT provides automation for this Extension, which means that once you are connected to the host using this extension you can use RFT recorder to read the content of the screen.
You may want to look at [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/test-terminal-based-applications-automatically/) to see how it works.